# Don't break on handled exceptions in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

Is there a way to tell the Visual Studio 2008 not to break on exceptions that are caught and handled? It's annoying to have to hit continue when there are many handled exceptions that pop up during run-time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Click Debug, Exceptions, and uncheck everything.

Comment: Well I still want it to catch exceptions that haven't been handled, I just don't want it to break if the exception is already caught. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes; it will always break on unhandled exceptions

Comment: Really? Dunno why I never noticed that, but I guess you're right!